# splitting array into array of arrays

Tags: php

I have an array of strings that are sentences and I need to split it into multiple arrays of words. I tried to use array_chunks but I would have to do it twice to get what I want and I cant access each individual element of the split array to array_chunk it again.

Sorry if its confusing basically what I want is;

```
$arr="this is a", "sentence and", "this is stackoverflow"
```

Split into:

```
$arr1="this", "is", "a"
$arr2="sentence", "and"
$arr3="this", "is", "stackoverflow"
```

this is what i have tried

```
$chunk=(array_chunk($userinf,1));
//$chunks=(array_chunk($chunk,1));
//print_r($chunks);
for( $i=0;$i<count($chunks);$i++ ){
do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just traverse the existing array and reassign the values as a new array. Like this...

```
$arr = ["this is a", "sentence and", "this is stackoverflow"];

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {

    $arr[$key] = explode(" ", $val);

}
```

Result is...

```
$arr = [["this","is","a"],["sentence","and"],["this","is","stackoverflow"]]
```

Comment: how would i access each element?

Comment: Just like I showed you using [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/foreach)